# submitting an array of text inputs using php and mysqli

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Still trying to get my head around submitting arrays and using Mysqli.

So on a form I want to have several inputs:

```
<form action='newmem2.php' method='post'>
  <input type="text" name="memname[1]"><br>
  <input type="text" name="memname[2]"><br>
  <input type="text" name="memname[3]"><br>
  <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

then on newmem2.php I have:

```
$newmember = $_POST['memname'];
$sql = 'insert into members (name,active)values(?,?)';
$update = $db->prepare($sql);
   foreach($newmember as $memname => $val) {
     $update->bind_param('si', $val, '1');// the 1 indicates I want to force that
     entry.
     $update->execute();
   }
```

the print_r($_post) revelas:
`Array ( [memname] => Array ( [1] => joe [2] => bob [3] => eric ) )`

but there isn't anything submitted to the database. (yes I have a valid connection).
Searches indicate usage of

Also, if I only have one name entered, how can I go about skipping the remaining fields so I am not submitting empties?

Comment: Turn up your error reporting. You can't use constant values (like `'1'`) in `bind_param`. You must use variables as they are passed by reference

Comment: @Phil turn up error reporting? how?

Comment: While developing, your `php.ini` file should have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On`. You can also put `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before creating your database connection for better error reporting from the *mysqli* extension

Comment: @Phil the variable did the trick `$active=1` then  `$update->bind_param('si', $val, $active)` now names are submitted!

Comment: @Phil thanks for the error reporting info. Any thoughts on how to handle empties?

Comment: try to output the aute generated sql insert statement and paste it on your terminal for debugging purpose..

about the skipping empty fields.. 
add is_empty condition before binding params and executing the code..

Comment: @Semi-Friends `foreach($newmember as $memname => $val) {
    if (!empty($val) ){
  $update->bind_param('si', $val, $active);
    $update->execute();}` did the trick, thanks